# Modify windows 10 focus assist option by script

Tags: windows, parameters, installation

I'm currently creating a MDT server to automate WIN10 install.
By default, focus assist is deactivated. I want it to be on "alarms only".

I would like to do it by batch, powershell or vbs, but if you have any other idea, I'll take it too.

I tried by registry but it was an echec.

Thanks a lot